# Where can I get a list of all of the Azure geographic-specific endpoints?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing an experimental authentication proxy that will bridge different authentication signature schemes:

- A custom scheme between the client and the proxy
- The existing shared access token between the proxy and the Azure endpoint.

I would like to reduce costs and increase speed and not transfer data out of the closest datacenter unless necessary, or desired by the client.  To solve this I'm thinking of 402/403 redirect the client at data.example.com to us-data.example.com, or uk-data.example.com.

Since I'll be using a wildcard certificate, I could handle the many DNS names as necessary to redirect the corresponding Azure service. (Cosmos, Media, Blob, etc)

Does a formula or JSON result exist that I could use to derive and maintain the site specific redirection pattern above?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/locations/

Answer (score 0):

Just summarize to help others who have  the same isuue:

As per the comment mentioned, the azure locations link is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/locations/).

Comment: If only there was a way to take a hostname and identify the location so a proxy can redirect to the nearest instance (preventing inefficiency)